# VUE.js | V-bind - Array & Filter

Tags: javascript, css, class, vue.js

I'm having an issue with an app him trying to put together. I'm using Vue.js to build my front-end and I'm trying to bind 2 classes to a div. It's also in a v-for loop.

My first bind have a filter. It's working properly when I use it alone.

```
v-bind:class="item.category | formatCategory"
```

What I get from my API is a category that have uppercase and spaces. I need it to be clean without those but also need it formated somewhere else in my code.

This is the filter I created:

```
  formatCategory: function (value) {
    if (!value) return ''
    value = value.toString()
    value = value.replace(/\s/g, '') //remove spaces
    return value.toLowerCase(); //everything in lowecase
  }
}
```

I also need that bind to show when a object is processed.

```
v-bind:class="{completed: item.completed}"
```

This v-bind is also working when used alone. I'm now trying to combine both v-bind to get one super component.

```
v-bind:class="[{completed: item.completed}, item.category | formatCategory]"
```

It's not working with this here. I'm definitely doing something wrong but after multiples hours of Google, I can't find why!

```
<div
    class="column-object"
    v-bind:class="[{completed: item.completed}, item.category | formatCategory]"
    v-for="(item, i) in itemRows"
    v-bind:key="i"
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use filters this way.

From the documentation:

> Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply common
>   text formatting. Filters are usable in two places: mustache
>   interpolations and v-bind expressions (the latter supported in
>   2.1.0+). Filters should be appended **to the end** of the JavaScript expression, denoted by the “pipe” symbol:

Your `|` is interpreted as usual binary OR.

I would suggest to create a computed property which will return array of classes. Or you may use your filter as a function `formatCategory(item.category)`.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem silly, but you can't mix the `filter` function in the `array-object` syntax. This is because vue actually uses a regex lookbehind to capture the value and interpret it from the $data properties on the component.

Instead, just pass the value to the function, as that's all it is anyway, a pure function:

```
v-bind:class="[{completed: item.completed},  formatCategory(item.category)]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I was able to make it work like this:

```
v-bind:class="[{completed: item.completed},formatCategory(item.category)]"
```

I had to place it inside a methods. I'm not sure about the difference of a method and a computed property, but I'm going to read about that now!

```
methods: {
    formatCategory: function(value) {
      if (!value) return "";
      value = value.toString();
      value = value.replace(/\s/g, "");
      return value.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
```

Thank you to both of you!